# How to force HTTPS for a single API in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, security, https, passwords

There is a page in our Spring Boot app which allows users to enter LDAP credentials. Since the app allows both http and https support. this is problematic, as the password sent back to the user from the server is in plain text and the user can view it using developer tools.

Question - would enforcing HTTPS for this particular API solve the problem? If so, how to enforce it for only a single API? If not, what other solutions would work?

Comment: By "single API" you mean single endpoint? (e.g. requiring `/endpoint1` to be accessed via https while `/endpoint2` can be http?)

Comment: /endpoint1 can be accessed only with https, /endpoint2 can be accessed by both http and https.